# BHO change object navigator

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

I now learning BHO, me need write plugin for InternetExplorer, which will be edit values in navigator object, for example property appName.
On this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535867%28v=vs.85%29.aspx this property not read only.
A am use C#.
Do you think it is possible to edit navigator.appName and how? Please!, help!
Me need this for functional testing my web applications, I am php programmatic and writing BHO very hard for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly - you need to override read-only properties of Navigator. It can be done without BHO/Plugins but with pure JavaScript code.

If you really need it - you can define a new property on top of the Navigator old property via defineProperty method:

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, "appName", { value: "newValue" });
```

IMO, it's a dirty hack and please think twice whether you would like to proceed with such approach of functional testing.